# What construction materials could enable a capillary effect to raise water?

Tags: material-science, biophysics, fluid-statics

Are there materials (possibly in research stage) which are investigated as replacement for piping and pumping systems in construction work to transport water from the ground to elevated floors in civil buildings?

Answer (score 1):

note that capillary lift in a vertical column only exists as long as a meniscus exists at the top of the capillary column. as soon as you begin to pull the water in the column out of it, the meniscus disappears and now you have to perform the usual work against gravity to move more water up.

This means that capillarity cannot be used to transport water in bulk "for free" to the upper floors in a building.

Comment: Could the water be „harvested“ from a faucet below the meniscus? Still any input on the material? What if just placing a tree within a building?

Comment: Trees and all other vascular plants use active transport to convey water upwards- not pure capillarity. the only way to "harvest" water from the top of a capillary is by absorption into another material of higher capillarity, then how to get the water out? No material science solution to this problem. Just use pipes and plumbing! -NN

Comment: Condensation of water that evaporates over the leaves surfaces?